# Can't save meta box data in Wordpress using custom post types

Tags: wordpress

All I really want is for the meta box data to be saved A) as an accessible global variable inside the loop and B) to save the data to the textbox so that when the user presses update what they have written appears in the textbox until it is updated again. Currently, i know it doesn't fit the criteria for B), and I'm not sure whether or not it is accessible as a global variable in the loop. Any help?

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'testimonial_text_box' );

function testimonial_text_box() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'testimonial_text_box',
        __( 'Testimonial Text:', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
        'testimonial_text_box_content',
        'testimonial',
        'normal',
        'high'
    );
}

function testimonial_text_box_content( $post ) {
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );  
    $text = isset( $values['my_meta_box_text'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['my_meta_box_text'][0] ) : ”;  
    $selected = isset( $values['my_meta_box_select'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['my_meta_box_select'][0] ) : ”;  
    $check = isset( $values['my_meta_box_check'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['my_meta_box_check'][0] ) : ”;  

    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'testimonial_text_box_content_nonce' );
  $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key', true );
  echo '<label for="testimonial_text">';
       _e("Text body of the testimonial:", 'myplugin_textdomain' );
  echo '</label> ';
    echo '<br/>';
  echo '<textarea align="top" id="testimonial_text" name="testimonial_text" value="'.esc_attr($value).'" style="width:100%;height:200px;margin:5px -20px 3px 0;" /></textarea>';
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'testimonial_text_box_save' );
function testimonial_text_box_save( $post_id ) {

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
    return;

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['testimonial_text_box_content_nonce'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
    return;

    if ( 'testimonial' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
        return;
    } else {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;
    }
    $testimonial_text = $_POST['testimonial_text'];
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'testimonial_text', $testimonial_text );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems with your code:

1. Unnecessary block (it's not related to the goal at hand):

   ```php
   $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );  
   $text = isset( $values['my_meta_box_text'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['my_meta_box_text'][0] ) : ”;  
   $selected = isset( $values['my_meta_box_select'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['my_meta_box_select'][0] ) : ”;  
   $check = isset( $values['my_meta_box_check'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['my_meta_box_check'][0] ) : ”;
   ```
2. You're saving `testimonial_text` with:

   ```php
   update_post_meta( $post_id, 'testimonial_text', $testimonial_text );
   ```

   but getting `_my_meta_value_key` with:

   ```php
   $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key', true );
   ```

   Change the `get_` to `testimonial_text`.
3. A `textarea` doesn't have `value`, the content goes inside the open/close tags:

   ```php
   echo '<textarea id="testimonial_text" name="testimonial_text" />'.esc_attr($value).'</textarea>';
   ```
4. The hook `save_post` takes 2 arguments:

   ```php
   add_action( 'save_post', 'testimonial_text_box_save', 10, 2 );
   function testimonial_text_box_save( $post_id, $post ) { /* code */ }
   ```
5. There's a non-working if/else that should be like:

   ```php
   if ( 'testimonial' !== $post->post_type )        
       return;

   if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) )
       return;
   ```

To use the post meta in the front end, just use `get_post_meta()`.

Comment: Bit late, but after reviewing the code you've posted (as well as getting some PHP experieince under my belt) that is the correct answer. Thanks!